E bot.ftech_channel raises error with pytest AttributeError: '_MissingSentinel' object has no attribute 'is_set'
I have a discord bot which needs to fetch guild and channels. If I get none from bot.get_guild(), I try to fetch_guild through api. The code looks something like this:
async def get_or_fetch_guild(obj_id, bot, guild):
    guild = bot.get_guild(obj_id)
    status = 'SUCCESS'
    status_code = 200
    if guild is None:
        try:
            guild = await bot.fetch_guild(obj_id)
        except discord.errors.NotFound:
            guild = None
            status = 'INVALID_GUILD_ID'
            status_code = 400
        except discord.errors.Forbidden:
            guild = None
            status = 'FORBIDDEN'
            status_code = 403
        except discord.errors.HTTPException:
            guild = None
            status = 'HTTP_EXCEPTION'
            status_code = 400
    return guild, status, status_code

It works fine normally but when I write test case for the api using the above code as utility function, I get this error:

 if not self._global_over.is_set():  
 E       AttributeError: '_MissingSentinel' object has no attribute 'is_set'
 venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/http.py:605: AttributeError


I am writing test case for this api call:
@router.get("/guild/{guild_id}/roles", response_model=role_schema.AllRoleData)
async def get_all_roles(
    guild_id: int,
):
    print("get all roles api called")
    guild, status, status_code = await get_or_fetch(guild_id, "guild", bot)

    # try to get the guild through api call if not found in cache
    if guild is None:
        print(f"Guild not found with id: {guild_id}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status_code, detail=status)

This is one of the test case that is giving error:
@pytest.mark.asyncio
@patch("discord.Client.get_user")
@patch("discord.utils.get")
async def test_assign_role_invalid_guild(
    mock_get_user, mock_get, bot: Tuple[commands.Bot, str], test_client
):
    user = dpytest.get_config().members[0]
    role = dpytest.get_config().guilds[0].roles[0]
    # Create mock user, guild, member, and role objects
    mock_user = MagicMock(spec=discord.User, id=user.id, name="user")
    mock_member = MagicMock(spec=discord.Member, id=user.id, name="member")
    mock_role = MagicMock(spec=discord.Role, id=role.id, name="role")

    # Make member.add_roles an AsyncMock
    mock_member.add_roles = AsyncMock()
    # Set up the return values of get_user, get
    mock_get_user.return_value = mock_user
    mock_get.return_value = mock_role

    # Call the assign_role endpoint
    response = test_client.post(
        "/api/v1/dashboard/assign/roles",
        json={"discord_user_id": user.id, "discord_guild_id": "1234", "role_ids": [role.id]},
        headers={"X-Sizzle-External-Client-Key": settings.SIZZLE_BOT_API_SERVER_KEY},
    )

    assert response.status_code == 400
    assert "detail" in response.json()
    assert response.json()["detail"] == "INVALID_GUILD_ID"

Can anyone suggest a solution?
